# How to view best answer in StackOverflow ? Sort by best answer - display first?

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

Does StackOverflow elevate the best answers to top?

Or is there any sort option available, to view the most upvoted answer of the question, or order by more reputation first? Can we have this feature?

This would help to quickly find the best/reliable answer while programming.

Comment: There's probably no _best answer_. Depends on what you're actually looking for.

Comment: Agree,I mentioned to sort by reputation option.

Comment: Reputation even guarantees less improvement vs votes perhaps. Even high-rep users may fail on giving good answers. The swarm intelligence expressed by upvotes may be more consolidate.

Comment: Agree, good point. I wanted option to view by max voted answers. Do you know?

Answer (score 9):

You're free to order any question based on the score, created date, or last modified date:

> [image]

Comment: Can you please give some more input. Say question ABCD has four answers. How to view answers sorted by more reputation(best) one instead of scroll down to view best answers.

Comment: @Nara I just showed you exactly how.  You use the links shown to determine the sort order of answers.

Comment: @Servy What's _the score_ actually? How does it calculate from votes-cast of the present question and answers?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Score is the sum of upvotes and downvotes on a post.

Answer (score 1):

> [*"Agree, good point. I wanted option to view by max voted answers."*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275611/how-to-view-best-answer-in-stackoverflow-sort-by-best-answer-display-first/275616#comment111703_275611)

As you're asking for how to find the most upvoted **answers** explicitly, IMHO the closest thing you can get is searching, and sorting by *relevance* (which is the default):

[image]

I'm not completely sure, how the relevance sorting algo works, but I'm pretty sure the votes cast on the existing answers plays a roll there.

Another option seems to be searching by tags only, and selecting *frequent* for ordering of the results:

[image]